# PDO run query inside while loop showing only 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to get categories and sub categories. Both tables has different tables. Please see the below table structures:

> tbl_category

```
 id | name   | order_number
  1 | Allgem | 1
  2 | Vorauss| 2
  3 | Support| 3
  4 | Zielste| 4
```

> tbl_sub_category

```
 id | cat_id   | sub_name
  1 | 1        | Alter 
  2 | 2        | Trainingsalter
  3 | 2        | Kader
  4 | 2        | Wettkampfsystem
  5 | 3        | Trainingsort
  6 | 3        | Team
  7 | 4        | Betreuung
  8 | 4        | Unterstuetzung
```

I have tried with the below answer:

[query inside while loop only shows 1 result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950229/query-inside-while-loop-only-shows-1-result?answertab=active#tab-top)

Below is my code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
    <p style="text-align: center;font-weight: 600">Categories</p>
    <?php
        $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_category');
        $query->execute();
        $i = 1;
        $firstResults = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $ID = $row['id'];
    ?>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu<?php echo $i;?>" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></a>
        <?php 
            $querySub = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_sub_category WHERE cat_id=:cat_id');
            $querySub->execute(array(':cat_id' => $ID));
            while ($rowSub = $querySub->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu<?php echo $i;?>">
            <li><a href="?cat=Allgem&sub=Beschreibung"><?php echo $rowSub['sub_name']; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
</ul>
```

Please help us guys!!!!

UPDATED QUESTION:

[image]

Please see the above table relationship of both tables.

Comment: you should use JOIN

Comment: Wha? `Both tables has different tables`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes both are different tables

Comment: There should be a link between the two tables. Go back to your entity relationship diagram. I hope you have one

Comment: @Akintunde - there is a link between the tables, `c.id = sc.cat_id`  obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a Join like this

```sql
SELECT
    c.name,
    sc.*,
    c.order_number
FROM
    tbl_sub_category AS sc
INNER JOIN
    tbl_category AS c ON c.id = sc.cat_id
```

You can test this one here
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vX8Z6jPbaweBDjGtvPwRdP/0

There is no need to pull, `c.id` *(it would be ambiguous, anyway )* and you already have it as `sc.cat_id`.  So, what we really need is everything from the sub-category table *(alias as `sc`)* and just the category name and order_number from the category table *(aliased as `c`)*.

If you need main categories without a sub-category then you can do a Left Join. You'll have to account for some null values, which would be the case no matter what.

```sql
SELECT
    c.name,
    sc.*,
    c.order_number
FROM
    tbl_category AS c
LEFT JOIN
     tbl_sub_category AS sc ON c.id = sc.cat_id
```

And this one here
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdgD9K5TYnD79boUdaC57k/0

I intentionally left sub-category 6 & 7 out, to show how it works for the left join, this way cat 4 doesn't have any sub-categories.  It's a good Idea to have a proper test case if you need to account for those.

After you get your query sorted out *(one call instead of O{n} calls)*, you'd follow pretty standard procedure, structure the data then output it.  Like so:

```php
<?php
$data = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
?>
```

First thing to do is group the data by category, so we can have a item for category and several items for sub-categories. The category name `$row['name']` works great for this, because we need it outside of the inner foreach loop.
As mentioned by @YourCommonSense, in the comments, we can easily do this by using `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` and putting the `name` column as the first column in our selection list.

Which will give you something like this:

```
$data = [
    'Allgem' => [
        ['id'=>'1','cat_id'=>'1','sub_name'=>'Alter','name'=>'Allgem','order_number'=>'1'],
    ],
    'Vorauss' => [
        ['id'=>'2','cat_id'=>'2','sub_name'=>'Trainingsalter','name'=>'Vorauss','order_number'=>'2'],
        ['id'=>'3','cat_id'=>'2','sub_name'=>'Kader','name'=>'Vorauss','order_number'=>'2'],
        ['id'=>'4','cat_id'=>'2','sub_name'=>'Wettkampfsystem','name'=>'Vorauss','order_number'=>'2'],
    ],
    'Support' => [
        ['id'=>'5','cat_id'=>'3','sub_name'=>'Trainingsort','name'=>'Support','order_number'=>'3'],
        ['id'=>'6','cat_id'=>'3','sub_name'=>'Team','name'=>'Support','order_number'=>'3'],
    ]
];
```

As you can see, now we have a structure grouped by the cat ID.  This will work much better for what we need to do next. Because we pre-format the data the way we want it makes our code simpler, more concise and easier to read.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
    <p style="text-align: center;font-weight: 600">Categories</p>
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($data as $cat_name => $sub_categories):
    ?>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#homeSubmenu<?php echo $i;?>" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $cat_name ; ?></a>
            <?php foreach ($sub_categories as $row): ?>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu<?php echo $i;?>">
                    <li><a href="?cat=Allgem&sub=Beschreibung"><?php echo $row['sub_name']; ?></a></li>
                </ul>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </li>
    <?php
        $i++;
        endforeach;
    ?>
</ul>
```

You can test it here, but it's near impossible to find a phpSandbox that allows you to mix HTML, PHP, save it, and output in HTML. So it's just the raw source html, but you can see it's syntactically correct and error free.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1030bfd98c73d12b718077363d30ac587166c6cb

On the topic of errors, you also had several other issues. Like the sub-link had a static address `<a href="?cat=Allgem&sub=Beschreibung">`.  You had `$row['cat_name']` which dosn't exist in your table schema *(its just `tbl_category.name`)*.  Another one is this `<p>` tag between the first `<ul>` and `<li>` I didn't see a reasonable way to fix that without changing the structure, because well the structure is the issue.  See below:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
    <p style="text-align: center;font-weight: 600">Categories</p> <!-- p tags shouldn't be here -->
    ....
     <li class="">
```

Personally, I would recommend using a dictionary list, or `<dl>`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp

Which would let you do something like this

```
<dl class="list-unstyled components">
    <dt><p style="text-align: center;font-weight: 600">Categories</p></dt
     <dd class=""><!-- instead of the li tag --></dd>
</dl>
```

Or just remove the `<p>` tag altogether?  Anyway, there may be other issues with your original HTML that I didn't see.  But I figure this should get you on the right track.

Cheers.

Comment: simple, Left join then

Comment: so in fact you need just `$data = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);`

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I actually never used that before it's not covered well on the php.net website.  So thanks, learn something new every day, 6 years PHP and never noticed that one.

Comment: Satisfied ( deleted )?  I'm tired been up about 27 hours, not that it matters in the grand scope of things.  But I'm just trying to help the OP out.   TBH, I'm surprised he didn't get like a billion down votes yet.

Comment: And Just FYI, I'm mostly self taught, and I blame the php.net site for lack of documentation on that fetch mode.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php  There is what like half a sentence about it?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks for your answer. It's really appreciated but it's now working. Please see the *updated question* I have attached the image

Comment: I posted my link not as reproach but just for your information. Sorry if it sounded like that, it wasn't my intention at all.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - cool if it's working, but I would really suggest running it in one query.  Searching inside a loop will query the DB once for the categories, and then one additional time for each category.  So if you have 30 categories, you would be making 31 separate DB calls.  If you have 100, it's 101 searches and so on.   It does depend somewhat on how many categories you plan to have, but its the most efficient way to do it IMO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - it's all good, it's not your fault there is a lot of, how should I put it, argumentative people on SO.  We want self policing and democracy, but we wind up with mob rules most the time.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, If you can go the code [tester](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1030bfd98c73d12b718077363d30ac587166c6cb) the child categoris UL is repeating for every child category.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - this would have been the case with your original *inner while loop* please see  `..while ($rowSub = $querySub->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu<?php echo $i;?>">..`  The fix is just move it outside of the foreach loop.   As I said you probably  still have other issue with your original HTML structure.  It's very hard for me to "guess" what you need the structure to be based off only a few lines of HTML.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - here I fixed that.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fc735f55cd082658cbf01330f011a35e0c8f120

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, Many thanks for fix it let me try now and will accept your code. I have an issue with the More parameter like `Where discipline_id=1 AND phase_id=1`.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - I don't know what this means `More parameter` as it's not in your original post

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix many thanks for your help and really appreciated!!! It's working now as should.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - sure thing, glad I could help.  I always try to find the best way to do something, instead of just fixing it.  It has to work, but often times there is a better way to do something.

Comment: @mageDev0688 - I learned something new while answering this thanks to @YourCommonSense, in 6+ years of coding I never noticed you can return the results grouped with `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`.  What I am saying, is the most important thing is to never stop learning.  That's the main reason I come on SO, is to help others learn, and occasionally learn something new myself.   Cheers!